# Two-way encryption which only the owner can view

Tags: encryption

This is related to : [Two way DB encryption secure even from the Admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192485/two-way-db-encryption-secure-even-from-the-admin)

I am developing a mail client, and which would pull emails from the user's IMAP. For faster retrieval speed, the client will cache the user's email in the database.

Right now all the emails' body are encrypted using two-way AES256, and each user has his own encryption key. However, to further secure the system, I am looking for a way such that the encryption is only two-way for the user, in case the database is compromised -- either through a data dump via injection or there's an unauthorized access (such as the attacker has obtained the password).

Can this be done?

Comment: Please be more clear about the attack vector you're trying to secure against. What is the scenario that you're trying to prevent?

Comment: Updated the question. The relevant part is "...either through a data dump via injection or there's an unauthorized access (such as the attacker has obtained the password)."

Comment: Why is the key in a place where the admin has access to it in the first place?

Comment: Where is the decryption done, on your server or the user's device?

Comment: Key is in the database, decryption is done on the server-side.